# 1 and 2 is 12 , 2 and 3 is 46 then what's 3 and 4? it's not 102

Tags: mathematics

How can these equations be true?

one and two equals twelve

two and three equals forty six

Then what's three and four? (It's not 102)

Comment: When someone posts an answer the works fine (102), you can't just edit to say it's not the answer. It means the puzzle didn't work. Two data points is way too few; there's lots of reasonable functions that can be fit to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's:

> $912$

$$\begin{align}
1\,\&\,2 &= (1\times1)(2\times1) \implies 12\\[5pt]
2\,\&\,3 &= (2\times2)(2\times3) \implies 46
\end{align}$$

> $$3\,\&\,4 = (3\times3)(3\times4) \implies 912$$ You multiply the first number to itself as the first set of digits, then multiply the first number to the second for the second set of digits. Then put them together into one number.

Comment: i agree, this was exactly what i was thinking +1

Answer (score 4):

Three and four is

> 102.

The algorithm is:

> put the two given digits together to form a 2-digit number, and then multiply by the first of them.

Comment: Partially right but it's not the correct answer ..

Answer (score 0):

> I note the numbers are spelled out. So, while rand al'thor's approach is probably correct, the intended answer might be 'one hundred two'

Comment: If that's true, then the title is wrong since it uses numbers for 12 and 46.

Comment: Well, I'll be. It does. If only I had scrolled up one more notch.

Answer (score 0):

102 is also an answer.

This is how:

$12=1^2\cdot10+1\cdot2$

$46=2^2\cdot10+2\cdot3$

$102=3^2\cdot10+3\cdot4$

according to this operator:

$O(x,y)=x^2\cdot10+x\cdot y$

Comment: Yes but the question was not complete .. so I added "it's not 102"

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the accepted answer satisfies the criteria, though additionally it could be:

> 2712 -> $3^3=27$ & $3\cdot4=12$